# Jekyll Scss Converter encounters an error

Tags: sass, jekyll

I can't seem to be able to convert my scss files.

I have a file `assets/css/warriors.scss` that includes the following:

```
---
---
@import "charhub", "warriors";
```

Under `_sass` I have both a file `charhub.scss` and a file `warriors.scss` with the css in it.
However this gives me the following error

> Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/warriors.scss':
> expected "{".

Removing the double `---` from the `assets/css/warriors.scss` file removes the error, however then it also doesn't seem to convert the scss file into a css file as needed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show the entire directory and file structure of the SCSS and CSS files?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I'm not sure what exactly you're missing. Do you want me to show the entire content of the folders `assets/css/` and `_sass/` ?

Comment: The file on its own looks fine, but it imports `_sass/charhub.scss` and `_sass/warriors.scss`, which might contain the errors? Do the files exist?

Comment: @BenjaminW. The files exist in the folder `_sass/` as mentioned above. They work fine if I use them as CSS files as-is, they also work if I try to only import one of them.

Comment: Do the imported files contain the `---` front matter lines? Only the main SCSS file needs them.

Comment: @BenjaminW. The files in the `_sass` folder do not contain the front matter lines.

Comment: Do they work, individually, here? https://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: @BenjaminW. copy & pasting the files into the link you sent me doesn't seem to throw any errors or similar. Trying them out individually on my page also works

Comment: Is the repo public?

Comment: @BenjaminW. unfortunately no

Comment: Can  you reproduce it with a basically empty repo that contains like one post and just the CSS and SCSS files?

Answer (score 1):

At least in my local case, I had two files:

`assets/css/main.scss` and `_sass/main.scss`

And `assets/css/main.scss` imported `_sass/main.scss` and apparently now it's not possible anymore to have those files have exactly the same name. I renamed `assets/css/main.scss` to `assets/css/main_style.scss` and fixed the import.

See more information here: https://jekyllrb.com/news/2022/12/21/jekyll-sass-converter-3.0-released/#dropped-support-of-importing-files-with-the-same-filename-as-their-parent-file